# What make TEA18362T by NXP to work upto 75W?

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, power-management

I am planning to develop SMPS for 24V-4A using TEA18362T, but according to datasheet it useful up to 75W output power. Even online design tool by NXP works up to 75W.

- Is it possible to design and get work from such controller beyond its rated capacity ?
- Which constrain make it to ideally work for < 75W ?
- Can we mask this limit ?

Other company like ON Semiconductor have such controllers but they don't mention such power limit for controller.

Comment: Since these controllers drive an external MOSFET, there is no upper *theoretical* limit for the converter, typically a flyback. I have seen little TSOP6 controllers designed to power 20-30-W applications successfully used in 100-W converters and above. However, low-power controllers have usually low internal bias currents (for optimized standby power) and may be more susceptible to noise than specifically-designed high-power controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The device is a "\$\color{green}{\text{green-chip}}\$": -

> *The TEA18362T is a controller IC for low-cost Switched Mode Power
>   Supplies (SMPS). It is intended for flyback topologies. The built-in
>   \$\color{green}{\text{GREEN}}\$ functions provide high efficiency at all power levels.*

And, if you read [this document](http://www.ti.com/download/trng/docs/seminar/Topic2MM.pdf) by Texas Instruments entitled: -

```
Green-Mode Power by the Milli-Watt
```

You'll see that there is legislation the suggests different architectures for flyback controllers depending on what power category they are in and, 75 watts is the limit for the low power devices. Hence the TEA18362T is suggesting that it has all the features to meet that legislation/regulation up to that power: -

> *The TEA18362T enables low-cost, highly efficient and reliable supplies
>   for power requirements up to 75 W to be designed with a minimum number
>   of external components.*

It doesn't say it can't support designs above 75 watts.